# How can I force gcc to use custom implementations of newlibc implemented functions?

Tags: linker, embedded, arm

I am working on embedded software for a ARM microcontroller (SAM7) and using Yagarto toolchain.

My code currently links libc.a. However I'd like to use a custom implementation of the builtin function ***memcpy*** that my code already has.

I have tried using **-fno-builtin and/or -fno-builtin-memcpy** as specified in the [GCC Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) but the linker still complains will the following warning:

```
contiki-crazy-horse.a(flashd_efc.o): In function `memcpy':
C:\Users\Melvin\GitRepo\projects\Amatis_Project\SAM7_Contiki\examples\er-rest-example/../../cpu/arm//at91sam7s-x/./flashd_efc.c:669: multiple definition of `memcpy'
c:/toolchains/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-memcpy.o):C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\string/../../../../../newlib-1.19.0/newlib/libc/string/memcpy.c:78: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rest-server-example-nosyms.crazy-horse] Error 1
../../cpu/arm/at91sam7s-x/Makefile.at91sam7s-x:181: recipe for target `rest-server-example-nosyms.crazy-horse' failed
```

What is the correct way to use custom implementations of certain gcc built-in functions?

Edit 1: Adding the linking command I am using. In the code below Porject.a is an archive file created with all the project's object files.

```
CC       = arm-none-eabi-gcc
CFLAGSNO = -I. -I$(CONTIKI)/core -I$(CONTIKI_CPU) -I$(CONTIKI_CPU)/loader \
       -I$(CONTIKI_CPU)/dbg-io \
           -I$(CONTIKI)/platform/$(TARGET) \
           ${addprefix -I,$(APPDIRS)} \
           -DWITH_UIP -DWITH_ASCII -DMCK=$(MCK) \
           -Wall $(ARCH_FLAGS) -g -D SUBTARGET=$(SUBTARGET)

CFLAGS  += $(CFLAGSNO) -O -DRUN_AS_SYSTEM -DROM_RUN  -ffunction-sections

LDFLAGS += -L $(CONTIKI_CPU) --verbose -T $(LINKERSCRIPT) -nostartfiles  -Wl,-Map,$(TARGET).map

$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -nostartfiles -o project.elf -lc Project.a
```

Comment: Also include the linker command line that generated this error.

Comment: @Clifford I edited the original post to add the information you requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is finding `memcpy()` in libc.a, then it is not conflicting with any "built-in", but rather with the newlib implementation. You may need also to specify -nostdlibs option and explicitly link libc.a and libm.a as necessary.

Object (.o) files are linked before library archives (.a) files are searched, so if a symbol is resolved by an object file, it will not be searched for in the archives. If you place your overrides in an static-link library, then you simply list it ahead of the standard library (or any other libraries that use the standard library) on the linker command line.

***[Added]*** *The following was originally a "comment" but should probably be in the answer; it is in response to "Edit 1" in the question, and the comment below about link order:*

Change `-nostartfiles -o project.elf -lc Project.a` to `-nostdlib -o project.elf -start-group Project.a -lc -end-group`. The switch `-nostdlib` disables default linking of both start-up files (i.e. `-nostartfiles`) and standard libraries. The library grouping causes the libraries in the group to be searched iteratively until no further symbols can be resolved, allowing out-of-order and circular dependencies like yours to be resolved. An alternative form for the grouping switches is `-( Project.a -lc -)`.

Comment: @Cliford. My mistake. You are right Is there a way to pick which implementation of the memcpy I want my code to link? 
I can't switch the linking order between Project.a and libc.a because my project has some stub functions that libc.a needs

Comment: @Mischief:  Alternatively, separate your newlib stubs from your project files `Project.a -lc stubs.a`.  Using an archive for your project files is an unusual thing to do; you could avoid the problem altogether by linking object files directly as is the norm.  Code in object files will always be used in preference to library code regardless of link order; so the the libc stubs will be resolved by any object code you link with matching symbols, and any object code will be resolved from other object code before the library code, so memcpy() will be correctly overridden even for calls within libc.

Comment: I agree with you on your comment about having the code in an archive is unusual. If/when I have my way it will be changed